# Laravel Lazy load

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, lazy-loading

I've got this in my controller:

```
return view('message.Message')->with([
            'reactions' => $message->reaction->load('user, user.corporation')->paginate(2)
        ]);
```

But the lazy load `->load()`. does not work. I receive:

```
Call to undefined relationship [user, user] on model [App\Core\Reaction\Reaction].
```

But the user relation is definitly there!:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

How could I get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using the right parameters in the call to load. I think you want

> load('user', 'user.corporation')

Actually I think if you load 'user.corporation', 'user' is automatically loaded, so you only need

> load('user.corporation')

Comment: Whoops sorry about that. But then I receive: ```Method paginate does not exist.```

Comment: Of course, because you must paginate the view, not the eager loading. But that's another answer for another error in your code.

Comment: thanks so it should be this?: ```'reactions' => $message->reaction()->paginate(2)->load('user', 'user.corporation')```

Comment: The question has been answered, mate.

Comment: It is good manners to approve and/or upvote an answer that solved the question.